# Make a button perform an SQL statement

Tags: php, mysql, button

I'm trying my luck here. I am currently developing a website wherein people should be able to send a message and add a user as a friend from that person's profile page. I have a button, namely [Add as friend] using the basic `<button></button>` clauses. What would be the best workaround to do this?

For example, I'd like the SQL statment: `INSERT into friends (uid, fid, isapproved) VALUES ('1', '2', '1')` when the [Add this friend] button is clicked.

I'm working with just php and MySQL for now. Any suggestion would be more than welcome. Thanks, guys.

Comment: Which part are you not clear on?

Comment: I somehow had the same thing in mind with what Fernando answered below. I just wanted to see which other methods are available out there hence the suggestion request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not using AJAX, something like this should be enough.

**addfriend.tpl.php file**

```
<form method="post" action="action_addfriend.php">
 <input type="hidden" value="<?=$userid;?>" name="userid" />
 <input type="submit" value="Add as Friend" />
</form>
```

**action_addfriend.php file**

```
<?php

if ($_POST)
{  
  $fid = htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($_POST['userid']));
  $fid = mysql_real_escape_string($fid);
  include("your_connectdb_file.php");
  mysql_query("INSERT into friends (uid, fid, isapproved) VALUES ('1', '$fid', '1')");
  mysql_free_result();
}
?>
```

Comment: I agree in with the method, but I recommend not using the above query.  This query leaves yo wide open to SQL injection.  Use PDO or mysqli with prepared statements for proctecting user supplied data in the $fid variable.

Comment: All right, validation and sanitization must be in hand if you are programming in a production server. By the way you should use -> mysql_real_escape_string()

Comment: @ray: there isn't anything that could brake that SQL

Comment: I was aiming for something like this. Thanks! +1 for the non-AJAX answer.

Comment: @Fernando, I see you're using mysql_real_escape_strings and not the very bad old mysql_escape_strings. You're correct that it's safe and I'm guilty a knee jerk reaction without more closely noticing that imporant detail.  Don't let my error detract from how strongly I still recommend use of PDO or mysqli with prepared statements for proctecting against injection and many other benefits over the original non-OO mysql fuctions.

Answer (score 3):

- Button calls `javascript` function.
- `Javascript` function posts (`AJAX`,possibly using jquery) to a php file 'addfriend'
- `PHP` file executes `mysql`, returns `JSON`
- `Javascript` function calls `callback` and shows return value

Comment: Thanks! I'm currently not using AJAX but is foreseeing it in the future so your answer helps a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If you are only using PHP as a scripting language without any javascript, then you should make that button direct to a page which handles the add friend request for the given user_id.

For a friend addition to work on the same page you would need to use javascript and Ajax to make a background call to a php file which will handle the request silently and return a response if it were successful.

Answer (score 0):

send AJAX request with POST and/or GET data to url responsible for adding friends, eg: mysupersocialnetwork.org/friend/add/
this page request will trigger php and php will execute script.